# $http(). Get a SyntaxError when passing an extra GET parameter with "?"

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs

I followed the documentation example to implement a fetch method. 
It works well as far as I add `?format=json` to `$scope.url`.

```
    $scope.method = 'GET';
    $scope.url = "/activite/273/usagers?format=json";

    $scope.fetch = function($event) {

        $scope.code = null;
        $scope.response = null;

        $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
          success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.users = data;
            $scope.search.status = $scope.userStatus;
            $('#UserList').modal('show');
          }).
          error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.response = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.userStatus = '';
        });
        $event.preventDefault();
    };
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [API documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http), it looks like you should be passing parameters in a separate `params` object any way. So:

```
$scope.method = 'GET';
$scope.url = "/activite/273/usagers";
$scope.params = {
    format: 'json
};
```

Comment: it doesn't seems to be mandatory. i managed to get it working without that. thanks anyway

Comment: Was not an epic bug-fix, see my answer. Thanks for your in put anyway, I will definitely use that.

Answer (score 1):

It was in fact a problem due to json format itself, all the `"` was replaced by `&quote;`. I fixed that and it solved the problem.

Comment: was not that hard but I could'nt see it in the browser at first. I noticed it via the Network inspector.